# Library to show the allowed of the full space in percents

Tags: php, jquery, css, charts

I wonder if there exist any library (jquery or css + php) to show the chart of the user space left.

Something like:

> You are using already 35% out of 100% of slots.

And it should be done with a chart, but I don't know if there exist such library for system like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either it is me missing something in your question or you can use any charting library you want, e.g.

- [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net/index.php)
- [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)
- [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
- …

---

So you're basically looking for a progressbar. You can achieve this quite easily using HTML and CSS, no need for a charting library, i.e.

```
<span class="progressbar"><span style="width: 140px;">70%</span>30%</span>
```

The outer `<span />` will be 200px, so set the width of the inner span dynamicall (using php or JS) to `percentage * 200px`. (You can use whatever value you feel like instead of 200px.)

```
.progressbar, .progressbar span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.progressbar {
    background-color: #c60000;
    width: 200px;
}
.progressbar span {
    background-color: #00c600; 
}
```

Tada, now fiddle a bit with the CSS and you'll have what you've painted.

Comment: Yea, I've seen those already, but I'm looking for something simple , here is the example: http://i.imgur.com/mqrpa.png
Rate up for my paint skills `:D`.

Comment: To whom it may concern: I think my answer was valid even without the update.